# Prove that EF is longer than AC

Tags: geometry

ABC is an isosceles triangle, M is in the middle of AC, prove that EF is longer than AC

[image: ABCtriangle]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fg3p6.jpg)

Comment: Done, now what?

Comment: Please share your answer

Comment: I have tried using geometry proving that the area EBF is larger than ABC

Comment: Please share the efforts that you've made in attempting to solve this problem on your own!

Comment: You've tried to put it on math.stackexchange without showing any effort. You could try to calculate the length of EF as a function of the angle $BEF$ and show it has a minimum at 45 degrees.

Comment: You're on the wrong path for this purpose (i.e., that comment ain't gonna get you an answer in the near future).

Answer (score 2):

By the [sine rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines), $|EM|:|EA|=|FM|:|FC|$ because $\angle EAM=\pi-\angle FCM$, $\sin(x)=\sin(\pi-x)$ and $\angle AME=\angle CMF$.

**However**, draw $EF$ vertical, therefore length $\infty$. By the Intermediate Value Theorem, $|EF|\gt|AC|$, as the length of $|EF|$ is a quadratic, and by symmetry, has a minimum with $|AC|$.

Comment: No, $\triangle AME$ is not similar to $\triangle FMC$: The first has a $135^\circ$ angle, the second does not.

Comment: use the sine law, with $\sin(x)=\sin(\pi-x)$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines; @QuangHoang

Answer (score 1):

Analytically,
suppose
$AB = BC = 1$.

Then
$M
=(1/2, 1/2)
$.

Let
$E = (0, 1+v)
$,
where $v > 0
$.

Then
line $EM$
is
$\frac{y-(1+v)}{x}
=\frac{1/2-(1+v)}{1/2}
=1-2(1+v)
=-1-2v
$
or
$y
=1+v-x(1+2v)
$.

Putting
$y=0$,
$x
=\frac{1+v}{1+2v}
$,
so
$F
=(\frac{1+v}{1+2v}, 0)
$.

$|AC|^2
=2
$

$\begin{array}\\
|EF|^2
&=(\frac{1+v}{1+2v})^2+(1+v)^2\\
&=(1+v)^2(1+\frac{1}{(1+2v)^2})\\
&=(1+v)^2(\frac{1+(1+2v)^2}{(1+2v)^2}\\
&=(1+v)^2(\frac{2+4v+4v^2}{(1+2v)^2})\\
\end{array}
$

According to Wolfy,

$\begin{array}\\
|EF|^2-|AC|^2
&=(1+v)^2(\frac{2+4v+4v^2}{(1+2v)^2})-2\\
&=\frac{2 v^2 (2 v^2+6 v+3)}{(2 v+1)^2}\\
&> 0 \qquad\text{ for } v > 0\\
\end{array}
$

Note that,
as $v \to -\frac12$,
this $\to \infty$,
which is reasonable,
since the line
goes parallel to
the $x$ axis.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you mention in a comment is viable.

Using different notation ...

[image]

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\;|\overline{OP^\prime}||\overline{A^\prime B^\prime}| 
&= |\triangle OA^\prime B^\prime| \\
&= |\triangle OAB| + |\triangle PBB^\prime| - |\triangle PAA^\prime| \\
&= |\triangle OAB| + |\triangle QBB^\prime| \\
&\geq |\triangle OAB| \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\;|\overline{OP}||\overline{AB}|
\end{align}$$

Thus,
$$\frac{|\overline{A^\prime B^\prime}|}{|\overline{AB}|} \geq \frac{|\overline{OP}|}{|\overline{OP^\prime}|} \geq 1$$